# auditable_id is going nil when using Audited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-audited

I'm using Audited gem for rails and auditing reocrds for one of my model and everything works fine but auditable_id is going nil in audits table.
This is happening because id of the object i'm auditing is int and audits table store auditable_id as uuid.
So how can i resolve this issue?
I tried following but i don't think this is a right way.

```
Audited.audit_class.as_user(current_user) do
    model.update()        
    audit = Audited::Audit.last
    audit.update(auditable_id: id.to_s.rjust(32,"0"))    
  end
```

above code does the work but i don't feel this is a right way to do it.
There must be some way to do it in better way.

Comment: Manoj, could please tell me. Do you have any updates?

Comment: @PavelKalashnikov No.